# Phonegap plugin for android is not working. Why?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, undefined

I cannot make an Android phonegap plugin work. Not even a single one of the examples I found nor my pathetic failures trying to create one by myself. I first tried with Tutorials like [this one](http://phpmyweb.net/2011/09/14/creating-a-plugin-for-phonegap-1-0-android/). They don't work for me. I always end up with a `Cannot call method of undefined` error.

So I tried something ready. Got [this project](https://github.com/isawred2/phonegap-android-plugin-tutorial) from github. It's just a simple plugin to show a toast. I checked everything that i learned on the tutorials:

```
//the package name in the java
package com.phonegap.toast;

//my class extends Plugin and has a simple show toast method.

public class Tutorial extends Plugin {
@Override
public PluginResult execute(String cmd, JSONArray args, String callback) {
    if(cmd.equals("toast"))
    {
        return showToast(args);
    }
    return null;
}

private PluginResult showToast(JSONArray args) {
    final String message;
    try {
        message = args.getString(0);
        ctx.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(ctx, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                myToast.show();
            }
        });

        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
    }       
}   

}
```

the plugin is defined in res/xml/plugins.xml

`plugin name="Tutorial" value="com.phonegap.toast.Tutorial"`

and no, if i put it on rex/xml/config.xml it also doesn't work

Last, the method that calls the plugin:

```
function createToast() {
  // i also tried window.Tutorial.showToast('Hello AndroidOpen'); with no success
  window.plugins.Tutorial.showToast('Hello AndroidOpen');
}
```

And here I get the same error again.

`10-22 15:39:07.770: E/Web Console(2885): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'showToast' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/main.js:123`

Any enlightened soul can explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I've been trying this for days, with many different plugins, both my own and even [this ones](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android) and I can't find out what is it.

Comment: As you can see in the error message, your error is in the javascript, not the Java code. In other words: you didn't define `window.plugins.Tutorial`, which is why you can't call `showToast()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here are a few things that are probably tripping you up. First if the config.xml file exists in res/xml then it will take precedence over plugins.xml. So you will need to add your plugin line to config.xml instead.

Make sure you are including the .js file for your Toast plugin.

Third, window.plugins has been deprecated away so you may need to modify the .js if you are using PhoneGap 2.0.0 or better. Check out my [blog post on the topic](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/08/so-you-wanna-write-phonegap-200-android.html). The root change is that you now need to new PluginName in your JS as it is no longer put in window.plugins by default.

Comment: Simon, you just saved me. I spent the past 5 hours staring at my code trying to understand what's happening. I was putting the plugin in "plugins.xml" but not in "config.xml"! Thanks a lot.